# Could not start video source - ONLY in chrome

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

My website is using a video stream based on peerjs/WebRTC.

This worked perfectly a few days ago. Yesterday I switched to SSL because you can't access media devices without it. Since then the video isn't working in Chrome. Everytime I open my website I get the following error message:

> DOMException: Could not start video source

This is my source code for the video stream:

```
let myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: "192.168.178.28",
  port: "3000",
  path: "/peerjs",
  key: "peerjs",
});
let myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true; // mute own video

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ // get video and audio from user
    video: {
      width: { max: 320},             
      height: { max: 240},
    },
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream); // add video to peer

    Socket.emit("giveAllUsers");
    Socket.on("allUsers", (data) => {
      for (let x of data) {
        if (x != myId) {
          connectToNewUser(x, stream); //connect to new users
        }
      }
    });
    myPeer.on("call", (call) => {

      call.answer(stream);
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {//new stream
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      });
      call.on("close", () => {//remove users video when call is closed
        video.remove();
      });
      peers[call.peer] = call;
      console.log(peers);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('error: ', error);
  });
```

The same error occurs in Edge.

However, it still works in Firefox AND in the mobile version of Chrome!

Does anyone have an idea what's happening? Why is SSL causing this in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox and the mobile version of Chrome?

Comment: Is any other application using the same camera?

Comment: nope, I made sure that nothing else is open that could use the cam

Comment: Chrome and Edge on W10 are very much the same; Chrome and Safari on IOS ditto. Does it work on Safari on IOS?

Comment: This is so weird. After my question it randomly started to work in Chrome. And now after 3 weeks it stopped working. Same error message as before. I'm pretty sure that I didn't change anything on my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

For some reason Chrome (and ONLY Chrome) tried to use the camera of my connected vr headset which didn't work. If some of you have this problem in the future: make sure that Chrome tries to access the right cam.